# Android: Video Recording Throws Error

Tags: android, video

So I'm trying to use the built in camera activity to record a video using the below code:

```
    Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileURI);
    videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 60);
    startActivityForResult(videoIntent, VIDEO_ACTIVITY);
```

During debugging, fileURI has a value of: file:///mnt/sdcard/Spootur/Videos/c14e0eb2-0737-4931-9898-e85d10bab74e.mp4, and videoIntent has an mExtras value of:

```
Bundle[{output=file:///mnt/sdcard/Spootur/Videos/c14e0eb2-0737-4931-9898-e85d10bab74e.mp4, android.intent.extra.durationLimit=60}]
```

When I start recording, it goes fine, but when I reclick the record button to stop recording, the camera app throws this:

```
05-11 01:08:11.325: E/AndroidRuntime(3748):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.renameTempFile(CamcorderEngine.java:1352)
05-11 01:08:11.325: E/AndroidRuntime(3748):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.doStopVideoRecordingSync(CamcorderEngine.java:849)
05-11 01:08:11.325: E/AndroidRuntime(3748):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CeStateRecording.handleRequest(CeStateRecording.java:69)
05-11 01:08:11.325: E/AndroidRuntime(3748):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CeRequestQueue.startFirstRequest(CeRequestQueue.java:123)
05-11 01:08:11.325: E/AndroidRuntime(3748):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CeRequestQueue.access$200(CeRequestQueue.java:32)
05-11 01:08:11.325: E/AndroidRuntime(3748):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CeRequestQueue$MainHandler.handleMessage(CeRequestQueue.java:60)
```

Any ideas of what could be causing this and how to fix it? Thanks!

Also: I can confirm that the recorded video file is at that URI.

Comment: Did you try by removing this line  videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileURI);
after that it shows exception?

Comment: Yes, and then it works fine. I don't see what the problem with my URI is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, I found in some case `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` doesn't work properly, 
SO the other trick way is, store your captured video file in `onActivityResult()`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
   {   
    try {
         AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(intent.getData(), "r");
         FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
         File videoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"<VideoFileName>.mp4"); 
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);

         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int length;
         while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
               fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
          }       
         fis.close();
         fos.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO: handle error
         }
    }
 }
```

Try the above code and let me know about your success.

Comment: That works great! Thanks so much, I never would have thought of that!

Comment: Thanks for this! Holy cow, how broken can the Android platform be?

Comment: Thank you very much. This error was showing up on Galaxy S3 (4.1.2) but not on Nexus 5 (5.0.1)

Comment: for getting images what should i edit in your code, caue its crashing for getting image, I just changed the format from mp4 to jpg