# Force Close when EXTRA_OUTPUT is specified with a URI that is not null for video capture

Tags: android, video, forceclose

When capturing video, I utilize:

```
cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 3000);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, vidUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1447);
```

This code used to work, but now if I specify a URI that is not null, the camera force closes before it shows the "Save" and "Delete" buttons.  If I leave the URI null, then the camera functions works fine, but then the vidURI is null when the camera returns control to the calling class.  I've tried:

```
SharedPreferences settings = mCon.getSharedPreferences(prefname,MODE_PRIVATE); 
        File f = new File(settings.getString("vidPath","sdcard")+"/"+vID+".3gp");
        vidUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
```

and I have tried:

```
values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "vid"+vID+".3gp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DESCRIPTION,"eCompliance Manager Video");
        vidUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Both to no avail.  What am I missing?

Here is the LogCat for the time before and after the Force Close:

```
  06-18 13:29:35.868: ERROR/TvOut-Observer(447): TvoutSetOrientation
06-18 13:29:36.398: ERROR/AxT9IME(620): WordSymbInit: 1
06-18 13:29:36.488: ERROR/SensorManager(27169): thread start
06-18 13:29:36.488: ERROR/SensorManager(27169): =======>>> Sensor Thread Running <<<========
06-18 13:29:36.498: ERROR/AXLOG(27169): GLSurfaceCreate**StartU[1340044176506]**
06-18 13:29:36.669: ERROR/AXLOG(27169): surfaceCreate**StartU[1340044176678]**
06-18 13:29:36.699: ERROR/Camcorder(27169): Initialize Camcorder Sound
06-18 13:29:36.789: ERROR/SecCamera-JNI-Cpp(27169): JNI_OnLoad
06-18 13:29:36.789: ERROR/SecCamera-JNI-Java(27169): SecCamera.open()
06-18 13:29:36.789: ERROR/SecCamera-JNI-Java(27169): SecCamera()
06-18 13:29:36.849: ERROR/Surface(27169): Surface::init token -2 identity 800
06-18 13:29:36.849: ERROR/AXLOG(27169): surfaceCreate**EndU[1340044176856]**
06-18 13:29:36.859: ERROR/CamcorderEngine(27169): resetPreviewSize()- recording size - mParameters is null
06-18 13:29:36.959: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPreviewSize (mVtMode=0) : requested preview size 640 x 480
06-18 13:29:36.959: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPictureFormat : jpeg 
06-18 13:29:36.979: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPreviewSize (mVtMode=0) : requested preview size 640 x 480
06-18 13:29:36.979: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPictureFormat : jpeg 
06-18 13:29:36.979: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): Invalid Iso value: movie
06-18 13:29:36.989: ERROR/AXLOG(27169): GLSurfaceChanged**EndU[1340044176998]**
06-18 13:29:37.019: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPreviewSize (mVtMode=0) : requested preview size 720 x 480
06-18 13:29:37.019: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPictureFormat : jpeg 
06-18 13:29:37.019: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): Invalid Iso value: movie
06-18 13:29:37.029: ERROR/AxT9IME(620): WordSymbInit: 1
06-18 13:29:37.079: ERROR/CameraService(325): OVERLAY CREATED....
06-18 13:29:37.089: ERROR/ShotSingle(325): startPreview - mUseOverlay(1)
06-18 13:29:37.089: ERROR/mm-camera(325): m5mo_set_preview_size E(size = 720*480)
06-18 13:29:37.089: ERROR/mm-camera(325): m5mo_set_preview_size X(size = 720*480), change sensor.op_mode to 2
06-18 13:29:37.109: ERROR/AxT9IME(620): SelLstBuild:sStatus = 4
06-18 13:29:37.109: ERROR/AxT9IME(620): mAWLinguistic.SelLstBuild:wStatus = 4
06-18 13:29:37.109: ERROR/AxT9IME(620): mAWLinguistic.SelLstPostShift:wStatus= 34
06-18 13:29:37.109: ERROR/InputMethodService(620): Unexpected null in startExtractingText : mExtractedText = null, input connection = com.android.internal.view.InputConnectionWrapper@405c1488
06-18 13:29:37.119: ERROR/AxT9IME(620): SelLstBuild:sStatus = 4
06-18 13:29:37.119: ERROR/AxT9IME(620): mAWLinguistic.SelLstBuild:wStatus = 4
06-18 13:29:37.119: ERROR/AxT9IME(620): mAWLinguistic.SelLstPostShift:wStatus= 34
06-18 13:29:37.369: ERROR/mm-camera(325): vfe_util_get_sensor_info: mode=3
06-18 13:29:37.369: ERROR/mm-camera(325): m5mo_video_config, sfd = 47
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): display_pp_conv_set_hsic_cfg() Values: Hue=0 Saturation=0.000000 Intensity=0 Contrast=0.000000
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): hsc_matrix[0][0]=1.000000  hsc_matrix[0][1]=0.000000 hsc_matrix[0][2]=0.000000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): hsc_matrix[1][0]=0.000000  hsc_matrix[1][1]=1.000000 hsc_matrix[1][2]=0.000000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): hsc_matrix[2][0]=0.000000  hsc_matrix[2][1]=0.000000 hsc_matrix[2][2]=1.000000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_rgb2yuv[0][0]=0.256800  rec601_rgb2yuv[0][1]=0.504100 rec601_rgb2yuv[0][2]=0.097900  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_rgb2yuv[1][0]=-0.148200  rec601_rgb2yuv[1][1]=-0.291000 rec601_rgb2yuv[1][2]=0.439200  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_rgb2yuv[2][0]=0.439200  rec601_rgb2yuv[2][1]=-0.367800 rec601_rgb2yuv[2][2]=-0.071400  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][0]=0.256800  hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][1]=0.504100 hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][2]=0.097900  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][0]=-0.148200  hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][1]=-0.291000 hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][2]=0.439200  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][0]=0.439200  hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][1]=-0.367800 hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][2]=-0.071400  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_yuv2rgb[0][0]=1.164400  rec601_yuv2rgb[0][1]=0.000000 rec601_yuv2rgb[0][2]=1.596000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_yuv2rgb[1][0]=1.164400  rec601_yuv2rgb[1][1]=-0.391800 rec601_yuv2rgb[1][2]=-0.813000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_yuv2rgb[2][0]=1.164400  rec601_yuv2rgb[2][1]=2.017200 rec601_yuv2rgb[2][2]=0.000000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][0]=0.999981  rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][1]=-0.000035 rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][2]=0.000040  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][0]=0.000013  rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][1]=1.000009 rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][2]=-0.000036  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][0]=0.000069  rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][1]=-0.000031 rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][2]=0.999949  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): cc_matrix[0][0]=1.000000  cc_matrix[0][1]=0.000000 cc_matrix[0][2]=0.000000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): cc_matrix[1][0]=0.000000  cc_matrix[1][1]=1.000000 cc_matrix[1][2]=0.000000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): cc_matrix[2][0]=0.000000  cc_matrix[2][1]=0.000000 cc_matrix[2][2]=1.000000  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][0]=0.999981  cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][1]=-0.000035 cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[0][2]=0.000040  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][0]=0.000013  cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][1]=1.000009 cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[1][2]=-0.000036  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][0]=0.000069  cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][1]=-0.000031 cc_matrix*rec601_yuv2rgb*hsc_matrix*rec601_rgb2yuv[2][2]=0.999949  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_lv[0]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_lv[0]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_lv[1]=255
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_lv[1]=255
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_lv[2]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_lv[2]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_lv[3]=255
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_lv[3]=255
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_lv[4]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_lv[4]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_lv[5]=255
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_lv[5]=255
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): mv[0][0]=0x200  mv[0][1]=0x0 mv[0][2]=0x0  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_bv[0]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_bv[0]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): mv[1][0]=0x0  mv[1][1]=0x200 mv[1][2]=0x0  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_bv[1]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_bv[1]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): mv[2][0]=0x0  mv[2][1]=0x0 mv[2][2]=0x200  
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): pre_bv[2]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): post_bv[2]=0
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): Calling the MSMFB_MDP_PP ioctl
06-18 13:29:37.379: ERROR/QCAbl(358): ioctl MSMFB_MDP_PP returned 0
06-18 13:29:37.479: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): Calling CAMERA_OPS_STREAMING_VIDEO
06-18 13:29:37.479: ERROR/mm-camera(325): postproc_set_key: Sending IOCTL_PICT_PP: PP_KEY = 0 4
06-18 13:29:37.479: ERROR/mm-camera(325): vfe_reset_vfe: vfe_util_sendcmd:3(rc = 1) 
06-18 13:29:37.479: ERROR/CAM_FD(325): Sensor Mode HFR off
06-18 13:29:37.479: ERROR/mm-camera(325): vfe_util_get_sensor_info: mode=3
06-18 13:29:37.489: ERROR/mm-camera(325): cam_set_vtmode : Enter with vtmode - (0)
06-18 13:29:37.489: ERROR/mm-camera(325): cam_set_vtCameraID : Enter with vtCameraID - (0)
06-18 13:29:37.489: ERROR/mm-camera(325): cam_set_vtOrientation : Enter with Orientation - (0)
06-18 13:29:37.489: ERROR/mm-camera(325): cam_set_vtDimension : Enter : width-(0), height-(0)
06-18 13:29:37.509: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): ignoring preview callback--1
06-18 13:29:37.509: ERROR/CeStatePreviewing(27169): invalid request id for current state
06-18 13:29:37.539: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): ignoring preview callback--0
06-18 13:29:45.968: ERROR/CameraEngine(27169): onOrientationChanged: orientation - unknown orientation
06-18 13:29:47.639: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPreviewSize (mVtMode=0) : requested preview size 720 x 480
06-18 13:29:47.639: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPictureFormat : jpeg 
06-18 13:29:47.669: ERROR/SecMediaRecorderJNI(27169): JNI_OnLoad(SecMediaRecorder)
06-18 13:29:47.669: ERROR/JNIHelp(27169): RegisterNatives failed for 'com/sec/android/secmediarecorder/SecMediaRecorder'
06-18 13:29:47.679: ERROR/CamcorderEngine(27169): maxFileSize = 4294967295
06-18 13:29:47.789: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPreviewSize (mVtMode=0) : requested preview size 720 x 480
06-18 13:29:47.789: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): setPictureFormat : jpeg 
06-18 13:29:48.000: ERROR/OMX-VENC-720p(325): WARNING: Requested i/p bufsize[40960],Driver's updated i/p bufsize = 520192
06-18 13:29:48.000: ERROR/OMX-VENC-720p(325): get_parameter: OMX_IndexParamVideoProfileLevelQuerySupported for Input port returned Profile:1, Level:2048
06-18 13:29:48.000: ERROR/OMX-VENC-720p(325):  venc_set_intra_period: nPFrames = 29 nBFrames = 0
06-18 13:29:48.000: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM8660(325): outputDev=2, inputDev=8388608
06-18 13:29:48.000: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM8660(325): doAudioRouteOrMute() rx 2, tx 105, mMode 0, mMicMute 1 mIsRealCall 0
06-18 13:29:48.060: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM8660(325): outputDev=2, inputDev=8388608
06-18 13:29:48.090: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325):  in startRecording : calling start_recording
06-18 13:29:48.090: ERROR/mm-camera(325): vfe_start_recording VPE mode turbo 0
06-18 13:29:48.090: ERROR/QualcommCameraHardware(325): runVideoThread E
06-18 13:29:48.090: ERROR/OMX-VENC-720p(325):  Allocated virt:0x43d20000, FD: 86 of size 565248 at index: 0
06-18 13:29:48.090: ERROR/OMX-VENC-720p(325):  Allocated virt:0x43daa000, FD: 87 of size 565248 at index: 1
06-18 13:29:48.230: ERROR/OMX-VENC-720p(325): ERROR: unsupported index 2130706449
06-18 13:29:54.516: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM8660(325): outputDev=2, inputDev=8388608
06-18 13:29:54.516: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM8660(325): outputDev=2, inputDev=0
06-18 13:29:54.516: ERROR/AudioHardwareMSM8660(325): doAudioRouteOrMute() rx 2, tx 3, mMode 0, mMicMute 1 mIsRealCall 0
06-18 13:29:54.616: ERROR/OMXCodec(325): EOS send command in wrong state (5)
06-18 13:29:54.686: ERROR/OMX-VENC-720p(325): ioctl VEN_IOCTL_CMD_READ_NEXT_MSG failed/stopped
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:205)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at java.io.File.init(File.java:189)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:139)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.renameTempFile(CamcorderEngine.java:1372)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CamcorderEngine.doStopVideoRecordingSync(CamcorderEngine.java:867)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CeStateRecording.handleRequest(CeStateRecording.java:69)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CeRequestQueue.startFirstRequest(CeRequestQueue.java:123)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CeRequestQueue.access$200(CeRequestQueue.java:32)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at com.sec.android.app.camera.CeRequestQueue$MainHandler.handleMessage(CeRequestQueue.java:60)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
06-18 13:29:54.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27169):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 13:29:54.706: ERROR/(447): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
06-18 13:29:59.741: ERROR/OverlayLIB(447): setPosition failed
06-18 13:29:59.741: ERROR/Overlay(447): int setPositionHandleState(overlay_control_context_t*, overlay_object*, overlay::overlay_rect&, int, int, uint32_t, uint32_t):Failed for channel 0
06-18 13:29:59.761: ERROR/OverlayLIB(447): setPosition failed
06-18 13:29:59.761: ERROR/Overlay(447): int setPositionHandleState(overlay_control_context_t*, overlay_object*, overlay::overlay_rect&, int, int, uint32_t, uint32_t):Failed for channel 0
06-18 13:29:59.791: ERROR/OverlayLIB(447): setPosition failed
06-18 13:29:59.791: ERROR/Overlay(447): int setPositionHandleState(overlay_control_context_t*, overlay_object*, overlay::overlay_rect&, int, int, uint32_t, uint32_t):Failed for channel 0
06-18 13:29:59.831: ERROR/OverlayLIB(447): setPosition failed
06-18 13:29:59.831: ERROR/Overlay(447): int setPositionHandleState(overlay_control_context_t*, overlay_object*, overlay::overlay_rect&, int, int, uint32_t, uint32_t):Failed for channel 0
06-18 13:29:59.861: ERROR/OverlayLIB(447): setPosition failed
06-18 13:29:59.861: ERROR/Overlay(447): int setPositionHandleState(overlay_control_context_t*, overlay_object*, overlay::overlay_rect&, int, int, uint32_t, uint32_t):Failed for channel 0
06-18 13:29:59.901: ERROR/Overlay(325): Overlay Control Channel is not fully setup yet
06-18 13:29:59.981: ERROR/AlarmManagerService(447): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=1, 1340045126.699000000
06-18 13:30:00.552: ERROR/WindowManager(447): rotation is : 0
06-18 13:30:00.562: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): setOrientation rotation effect 1
06-18 13:30:00.572: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.572: ERROR/TvOut-Observer(447): TvoutSetOrientation
06-18 13:30:00.692: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.752: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.772: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.782: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.782: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.802: ERROR/AlarmManagerService(447): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=1, 1340044260.000000000
06-18 13:30:00.832: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.862: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.892: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.922: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.952: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.962: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:00.992: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.042: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.082: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.112: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.142: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.172: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.192: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.223: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.273: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.293: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.313: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.333: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.363: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.423: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.433: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.473: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.503: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.533: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.573: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.603: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.643: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.683: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.713: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.733: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.763: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:01.803: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): ###### Ignore overlay setting because of issue that overlay is rotated when camer exit ######
06-18 13:30:05.897: ERROR/WindowManager(447): rotation is : 3
06-18 13:30:05.897: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(447): setOrientation rotation effect 1
06-18 13:30:05.897: ERROR/TvOut-Observer(447): TvoutSetOrientation
```

Comment: Please include the logcat errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this two questions (with its answers) can help you:

[Question & answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494839/verifiyandsetparameter-error-when-trying-to-record-video)

[Question & answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545760/android-video-recording-throws-error)