# Unable to create directory in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having trouble creating a directory with the following code. I have this in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And this is the code for creating the directory:

```
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/app");
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is the full error when I try and run the app:

> 06-06 00:48:25.054 19696-19696/com.cameraApp.cameratest D/MyCameraApp: failed to create directory
>   06-06 00:48:25.054 19696-19696/com.cameraApp.cameratest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   06-06 00:48:25.054 19696-19696/com.cameraApp.cameratest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.cameraApp.cameratest, PID: 19696
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cameraApp.cameratest/com.cameraApp.cameratest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
>                                                                                    at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:452)
>                                                                                    at com.cameraApp.cameratest.MainActivity.getOutputMediaFileUri(MainActivity.java:101)
>                                                                                    at com.cameraApp.cameratest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Help. :(

Comment: Problem is not in Creating folder. Problem is in getOutputMediaFileUri, where you try to find path

Comment: This is what I have there:    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501439/android-camera-capture-activity-returns-null-uri

Comment: It makes sense in a way, but I don't understand how to create a URI before the file exists?