# Forced close on calling this Record Class

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

When I call this `Record.java` class via `Intent` from another class and then click on the `button1`, i get a forced close exception. I want to know why this is happening. Also, the logcat says something like device disconnected "unable to create media player"

The code is:

```
public class Record extends Activity{
    Button btn1,btn2;
    MediaRecorder recorder;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.record);
            btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/sample.3gp");


                    try {
                        recorder.prepare();
                        recorder.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();

                    recorder = null;
                }
            });
     }

}
```

Here is the logcat output

```
  07-05 10:20:07.598: E/AndroidRuntime(841): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newaa/com.example.newaa.Recipient}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -1 < 0
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -1 < 0
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt(SpannableStringBuilder.java:110)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.example.newaa.Recipient$2.onTextChanged(Recipient.java:76)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2687)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2552)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:71)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2527)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:2427)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:5940)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1127)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1127)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:5919)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1454)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:835)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:807)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
```

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: @Rajesh I have done that now.

Comment: When do yo get the FC? While starting the activity or on press of the button? The stacktrace of the Exception causing the FC is missing. Please post the complete logcat output containing the stacktraces for `com.example.newaa.Record`

Comment: I got it on the click of the Button 1

Comment: Possible error is on Recipient.java:76. This code looks perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in com.example.newaa.Recipient class.
see this line number. at com.example.newaa.Recipient$2.onTextChanged(Recipient.java:76)
Hope you will find problem or post the code of your Recipient.java

Comment: No. How can the error be in Recipient.java when its calling the Record.java without any error?

Comment: According to your logcat :  
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -1 < 0
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt(SpannableStringBuilder.java:110)
07-05 10:20:07.609: E/AndroidRuntime(841):  at com.example.newaa.Recipient$2.onTextChanged(Recipient.java:76)

Comment: Maybe you have pasted the old log. Please make sure you have pasted the latest log.

Comment: Meanwhile you should try replacing this "/sdcard/sample.3gp" by this one  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() .getAbsolutePath() + "/sample.3gp"

Answer (score 1):

Make Code like Reuse any time and anyWhere. Here is code to directly call the mediarecorder with Context ref. and also use it's methods to handle it.

```
public class AudioRecorder {
  final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
  final String path;
  Context context;

  public AudioRecorder(Context context,String path) {
    this.context = context;
    this.path = sanitizePath(path);
  }

  private String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
      path += ".3gp";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
  }
  /**
   * Starts a new recording.
   */
  public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        Toast.makeText(context,"SD Card is not mounted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");

    }
    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }
    System.out.println("Full path of audio"+path);

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);   
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();


  }
  /**
   * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
   */
  public void stop() throws IOException {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
  }

  public void Release() throws IOException{
      recorder.release();
  }  

}**
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling the output file like that. Instead use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: you can use it like this. 
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    .getAbsolutePath() + "/temp.pcm");

Answer (score 0):

as you can see from [my answer to myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613299/1056359) from not too long ago, Android has an issue with setting the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` flag in the video capture intent. 
try getting the default file location instead and copying the video from there like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {   
      try {
          AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(intent.getData(), "r");
          FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
          File videoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"<VideoFileName>.mp4"); 
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);

          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int length;
          while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
             fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }       
         fis.close();
         fos.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle error
        }
   }
}
```